when I list accessible customers with Google Ads API, I get an error message
I have a question about the Google Ads API.
I've been trying to list accessible customers with the Google Ads API, but I keep getting a response of "invalid developer token." What do I need to do to fix this error? Basic access is enabled in my manager account, so it must be the code thats the problem. I think this is the case since I have a production account and not a test account.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var OAUTHURL    =   'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?';
        var VALIDURL    =   'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=';
        var SCOPE       =   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adwords';
        var CLIENTID    =   '504111780457-nslu2gim01j3c7optfbvjkd7trdgjgk9.apps.googleusercontent.com';
        var REDIRECT    =   'https://prompt.rototer.com/google-ads.html'
        var TYPE        =   'token';
        var _url        =   OAUTHURL + 'scope=' + SCOPE + '&client_id=' + CLIENTID + '&redirect_uri=' + REDIRECT + '&response_type=' + TYPE;
         function login() {
            var win         =   window.open(_url, "windowname1", 'width=800, height=600'); 

            var pollTimer   =   window.setInterval(function() { 
                try {
                    console.log(win.document.URL);
                    if (win.document.URL.indexOf(REDIRECT) != -1) {
                        window.clearInterval(pollTimer);
                        var url =   win.document.URL;
                        acToken =   gup(url, 'access_token');
                        tokenType = gup(url, 'token_type');
                        expiresIn = gup(url, 'expires_in');
                        win.close();

                        validateToken(acToken);
                    }
                } catch(e) {
                }
            }, 100);
        }
        function validateToken(token) {

        }

        function gup(url, name) {
            name = name.replace(/[[]/,"\[").replace(/[]]/,"\]");
            var regexS = "[\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
            var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
            var results = regex.exec( url );
            if( results == null )
                return "";
            else
                return results[1];
        }
       function validateToken(token) {
            $.ajax({
                url: VALIDURL + token,
                data: null,
                success: function(responseText){  
                    getUserInfo();
                },  
                dataType: "jsonp"  
            });
        }
      function getUserInfo() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://googleads.googleapis.com/v6/customers:listAccessibleCustomers?access_token=' + acToken,
                data: null,
                beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("developer-token", "REMOVED FROM CODE");
                },
                success: function(resp) {
                    user    =   resp;
                    console.log(user);
                    $('#uName').text('Welcome ' + customer.id);
                },
                dataType: "jsonp"
            });
        }

        function gup(url, name) {
            name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
            var regexS = "[\\#&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
            var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
            var results = regex.exec( url );
            if( results == null )
                return "";
            else
                return results[1];
        }

        function startLogoutPolling() {
            $('#loginText').show();
            $('#logoutText').hide();
            loggedIn = false;
            $('#uName').text('Welcome ');
            $('#imgHolder').attr('src', 'none.jpg');
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <a href='#' onClick='login();' id="loginText"'><img src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/b51a0a_7eb5ea51d71b41a08712f038f0f47289~mv2.png" width="200"></img></a>
    <a href="#" style="display:none" id="logoutText" target='myIFrame' onclick="myIFrame.location='https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout'; startLogoutPolling();return false;"> Click here to logout </a>
    <iframe name='myIFrame' id="myIFrame" style='display:none'></iframe>
    <div id='uName'></div>
</body>
</html>

